# How does bash handle waiting for backgrounded subcommands?

Tags: bash, unix, wait

In bash, if I execute the command `(sleep 60) & wait` then bash will wait for the 60 seconds to finish, but if I execute `(sleep 60 &); wait` then no waiting occurs.  What is the fundamental difference in these two cases (behind the scenes)?

Answer (score 0):

> `if I execute (sleep 60 &); wait then no waiting occurs.`

It is because `sleep 60 &` runs in the background of a forked child process not in the current process. When `wait` runs in current process it doesn't have any job to wait for.

For ex. when you run:

```
(sleep 60) &
```

`child sleep process` enters into jobs of the current shell only hence `wait` works.

To test this you can run:

jobs -l

and see the sleep process in background jobs:

```
[2]+ 74103 Running                 ( sleep 60 ) &
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Both of them look like they are running in the background to me...

Comment: @Kvass: See the edited answer. When `&` is done inside the the `( and )` then sleep runs as background job in child process but `(sleep 60) & wait` makes it enter into jobs list of current shell itself.

Comment: I still am unclear about why there would be a difference.  `(sleep 60) & wait` should background `(sleep 60)` right?  Why would anything enter into the jobs list of the current shell?

Comment: because `&` is outside `( and )` therefore sleep is in the background job of current shell

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate this with the help of a program that prints a process' pid and its parent's pid.

```
$ cat getpids.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("%d %d\n", (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    exit(10);
}

$ echo $$
2002
```

Our shell is process 2002.

```
$ ./getpids
2651 2002
```

This shows that getpids was run in a child process of the shell.

```
$ (./getpids)& wait
[1] 2656
2656 2002
[1]+  Exit 10                 ( ./getpids )
```

getpids was, again, run in a child process of the shell. The shell waits for it and displays its exit status.

```
$ (./getpids&); wait
$ 2658 1
```

Here, getpids is a child of init, process 1. That means that, by the time it called getppid(), its parent had exited.

```
$ ./getpids
2663 2002
```

Shell 2002 is still there. What happened was that, in this particular case, the shell decided that `(command&)` deserved to be run in a fork of the shell. That forked shell forked again, started getpids, then exited before getpids got around to running the getppid() call.

We can look more closely at this by using `strace` to see the system calls.

```
2002  clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb77c5938) = 2657
2002  wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
2657  clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0xb77c5938) = 2658
2657  exit_group(0)                     = ?
2002  <... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 2657
2658  execve("./getpids", ["./getpids"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
```

Shell 2002 forks and creates shell 2657, which forks and creates process 2658 and then exits. 
Shell 2002 waits and sees exited process 2657.
Shell 2658, which is now "orphaned" and thus has parent pid 1, execs ./getpids.